# Framing a differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Form the differential equation having solution as $$y=(\sin^{-1}x)^2 + A(\cos^{-1}x)^2 +B$$ where A and B are arbitrary constants.

My attempt: Differentiating the given equation once we get
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=2\frac{(\sin^{-1}x)}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} - 2A\frac{(\cos^{-1}x)}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$$
$$or,\sqrt{1-x^2}\frac{dy}{dx}=2(\sin^{-1}x) - 2A(\cos^{-1}x)....(1)$$
Differentiating (1) further & simplifying, we get
$$or,(1-x^2)\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}-x\frac{dy}{dx}-2(1+A)=0$$

The answer is given in the book as $$(1-x^2)\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}-x\frac{dy}{dx}-2=0$$

Pls suggest how do I get this form of equation.

Comment: I checked both equations with Mathematica. That given $y$ is solution only for the equation you get. It is not a solution of the equation given by the book...

Comment: Thanks for the update @AugSB